# Cause of "Method name must be a string"

Tags: php

```
public function run() { 
$this->step = $this->$_POST("step", 1);
$this->xml = new XMLFile();
$common_data = array(
                    'STEPCONTENT' => $this->get_step_content(),
                    'STEPNUMBER' => $this->step,
                    'STEPTITLE' => $this->get_step_title()
                    ); 
echo $this->parse($this->common_template, $common_data);
```

This gives the exception:

```
Fatal error: Method name must be a string in
    C:\xampp\htdocs\test\openad\install\InstallOpenAdServer.php on line 674
```

Why?

Comment: is this the only code? as I was not able to locate closing brace in you code

Comment: Do not expect us to treat this seriously. If you want an answer to a question then you need to put some effort into it. Simply copying and pasting a blob of code does not constitute a question.

Comment: Question can be salvaged, and as demonstrated by Venu, answered.  I'd say give new users some leeway.

Answer (score 2):

This is the culprit

```
 $this->step = $this->$_POST("step", 1);
```

You cannot use an $_POST super global array as a function. If you are trying to access the vairable from the $_POST, you can simple do this

```
$this->step = $_POST["step"];
```